# How do I get the sum of column from a csv within specified rows using dates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, plotly-dash

```
Date,hrs,Count,Status
2018-01-02,4,15,SFZ
2018-01-03,5,16,ACZ
2018-01-04,3,14,SFZ
2018-01-05,5,15,SFZ
2018-01-06,5,18,ACZ
```

This is the fraction of data to what I've been working on. The actual data is in the same format with around 1000 entries of each date in it. I am taking the start_date and end_date as inputs from user. Consider in this case it is:
start_date:2018-01-02
end_date:2018-01-06
So, I have to display a total for hrs and the count within the selected date range, on the output. Also I want to do it using an @app.callback in dash(plot.ly). Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with filtering by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for columns by condition and then `sum`:

```
df = df.loc[df['Date'].between('2018-01-02','2018-01-06'), ['hrs','Count']].sum()
print (df)
hrs      22
Count    78
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I tried doing it your way, it works. But, I have to pass variables start_date and end_date instead of directly mentioning date manually. I tried doing that, it shows me no error, but then the total is 0, for both the total counts. Help.!